# Is there any way I can copy values into a specific string position using memcpy()?

Tags: c, arrays, string, memcpy, memset

I'm struggling to find I way to get the following string using the string.h functions   memset(...), memcpy(...) and strcat(...):

0000001234abcd

I'm required to use memcpy and I can not find a way to do so without returning to the begining of the string.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

void main () {
    char string [15];

    memset((void *)string,'0',6*sizeof(char));
    memcpy(string,"1234",4);
    strcat(string,"abcd");

    printf("String: %s\n",string);
}
```

Output-> String: 123400abcd

If anyone comes up with an idea, I would appreciate it so much.

Comment: Is it possible that you wanted to write `memset((void *)string,'\0',6*sizeof(char));` instead of ...  `'o'` ...? I.e. you want to write bytes with value 0 so that there is a guaranteed string termination, instead of bytes with value 48 (the ASCII value of '0'). (I now see, probably not, or you should have set all 15 bytes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two main issues:

- forget to specify offset on use of `memcpy`
- not having string null terminated when applying `strcat`

Try this:

```
char string [15] = {0};

memset(string,'0',6);
memcpy(string + 6,"1234",4);
strcat(string,"abcd");

printf("String: %s\n",string);
```

Output: 0000001234abcd

Answer (score 3):

Pedantic version:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
  char string [15];
  const char substr1 [] = "1234";
  const char substr2 [] = "abcd";
  const size_t zeroes = 6;

  memset(string, '0', zeroes);
  memcpy(&string[zeroes], substr1, sizeof(substr1)); // includes null term
  strcat(string, substr2);

  printf("String: %s\n", string);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of defining the two `substr`s?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider It makes it possible to use `sizeof`. Alternatively, you could write `memcpy(&string[zeroes], "1234", sizeof("1234"));` but that gives code repetition, so it is more bug-prone and less maintainable. But of course this example is a bit silly given the artificial requirements.

Comment: Oh, I see, missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

You can fix that by writing `char string [15] = {'\0'};`. This will initialise *all* the string memory to zero (the first character is set explicitly to `\0`, the subsequent characters are initialised to zero by default).

What's currently happening is that `strcat` traverses `string` until it finds a nul-terminator, before it concatenates `"abcd"`. That process is currently emitting two extra characters due to your `memset` and that bit of *undefined behaviour* that I've already mentioned in your assuming that `string` is initialised to 0 when you write `char string [15];`